# Default value is used instead of User input in argparse

Tags: python, argparse

I am having issues writing the following argument in which I am trying to:

- if user inputs in a date (eg. 20180514), use the date as inputted by the user
- if no user defined date, use the default option as stated in the argument.

This is my code portion:

```
parser.add_argument(
    '--date',
    #type=str,
    action='store_true'
    default=datetime.now()-timedelta(days=5))
)

if args.date:
    # Use the User-inputted date
else:
    # Use the default date as stated
```

If I used `action` flag, I will get an error citing `__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'type'`. If I do not use `action` and using the `type` flag that I was initially using, the code sticks back to using the default value instead of the one inputted by user.

Appreciate for any advice. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you know what `action='store_true'` does? Also, I believe you are missing some commas

Comment: What is `args.past`? Your argument is named `date`.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you have `action='store_true'`?

It means that `argparse` will ignore whatever comes after `--date` and instead set `args.date` to `True` or `False` based on whether `--date` was provided or not.

You also don't need that `if`:

```
parser.add_argument(
    '--date',
    default=datetime.now()-timedelta(days=5))
)
```

Is essentially all you need. Just don't forget to convert `args.date` to a datetime object when you need it.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems:

- `if args.date:` will *always* be true, because it'll be the default value *or* the user-entered value, neither of which is false-y (datetime objects and non-empty strings never are).
- `store_true` is the wrong action to use, because that tells `argparse` that this switch takes no value (it'll set `args.past` to `True` when the user uses the switch, anything following `--date` is not seen as part of this argument). Leave it to the default `'store'`.

Also, `str` is the default type, and the wrong type if you want to parse the user input into a `datetime` instance.

This works:

```
parser.add_argument(
    '--past',
    default=datetime.now() - timedelta(days=5))
```

But now `args.past` is going to be either a *string* (user input), or a `datetime` instance (the default value). You probably want to use a `type=` argument that converts user input to a datetime object too. Such as:

```
def to_datetime(s):
    return datetime.strptime(s, '%Y%m%d')

parser.add_argument(
    '--past',
    type=to_datetime,
    default=datetime.now() - timedelta(days=5))
```

to accept dates in your prescribed YYYYMMDD format.

Demo:

```
>>> from argparse import ArgumentParser
>>> from datetime import datetime, timedelta
>>> def to_datetime(s):
...     return datetime.strptime(s, '%Y%m%d')
...
>>> parser = ArgumentParser(prog='demo')
>>> parser.add_argument(
...     '--past',
...     type=to_datetime,
...     default=datetime.now() - timedelta(days=5))
_StoreAction(option_strings=['--past'], dest='past', nargs=None, const=None, default=datetime.datetime(2018, 5, 9, 20, 42, 34, 806341), type=<function to_datetime at 0x10bf422f0>, choices=None, help=None, metavar=None)
>>> args = parser.parse_args()
>>> args.past
datetime.datetime(2018, 5, 9, 20, 42, 34, 806341)
>>> args = parser.parse_args(['--past', '20180514'])
>>> args.past
datetime.datetime(2018, 5, 14, 0, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import argparse

def isTimeValid(tm):
   try:
      return datetime.strptime(tm, '%Y%m%d')
   except ValueError:
      msg = "not a valid time: {0!r}".format(tm)
      raise argparse.ArgumentTypeError(msg)

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--date", nargs=1, type=isTimeValid, required=False, default=[datetime.now()-timedelta(days=5)], help="Optional date YYYYMMDD format.")
argslist = parser.parse_args()

indate = argslist.date[0]

print("type:{}  date:{}".format(type(indate),indate))
```

Please take a note on the default it is assigning a list. That will make sure user input and default return are same type.